# how to send email through gmail smtp in codeginiter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

My site is on Godaddy hosting which have PHP version 5.4.34. I used the codeigniters email library, I have configured the following settings in email.php under the config folder.

```
<?php
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'gmail account email';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'pass';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
?>
```

Here is my code in controller file.

```
      <?php
    $msg ='';
     $msg .='<h3>Thank you for register</h3>';
      $msg .='Please follow The bellow link.';       
     $this->email->from('smit@xyz.com', 'Kayah Photography');
     $this->email->to($_POST['email']);
     $this->email->subject('Kayah Photography: Registration');
     $this->email->message($msg);
     if($this->email->send()) {
        $html ='';
        $html .= '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">';          
        $html .='Please check your email for details'; 
           $data['error'] = '';
           $data['success'] = $html;
           //$this->load->view('admin/new_en', $data); 
           redirect('admin/signup');
       } else { // email else
             show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
       } // email else end  
   ?>
```

After all the above setting I am unable to solve the following error please anybody know how to fix this.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection refused)

 Filename: libraries/Email.php

 Line Number: 1689
```

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy blocks all outgoing SMTP connections on their hosting. You will have to use their SMTP relay servers instead, or use a different host.

http://help.godaddy.com/article/955

http://www.satollo.net/godaddy-using-smtp-external-server-on-shared-hosting

Comment: I used the godaddy's smtp host in codeigniter email library setting, it solves the Connection refused error but there is still some errors. finally I tried core php's mail function & it works.